# PIC disassembler Needed

Tags: embedded, pic, disassembly

I want to disassemble a hex file of PIC16F877A. Is there any good disassembler ? After disassembly is it possible to compile again ? What are the things I have to take care of ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a disassembly listing in MPLAB. Select the right device, import the hex file, View Program Memory. It should be possible to edit and reassemble. However, this is in PIC assembly language, you  mentioned compile, so are you thinking of trying to get C code back from hex? If so, that's much harder.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own is fairly simple.  and you can make the output re-assembleable if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Just use IDA Pro: http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/
It disassemble everything and it the best tool ever for it.